# Удаление нескольких записей из таблицы по одному условию

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//mysql
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id`='15' // тут все понятно, удаляем 15 id
```

а вот допустим надо грохнуть всех у кого возраст = 15. как такое сделать? сначала SELECT, и потом перебором через цикл? Одним запросом возможно?

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `age`='15' // таких записей примерно 'много'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `age` = 15
```

Это и есть сам запрос на удаление. СУБД сама найдет все записи у которых age = 15 и удалит их.

[image]

P.S.: будьте с запросами DELETE очень аккуратны, так как одна неверная цифра и удалятся совсем не те записи, которые хотелось.

Comment: ..мм интересно. у меня при таком запросе только 1 запись удаляется. т.е. дело не в запросе получается

Comment: Выполните запрос SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `age`= 15; - это выведете вам количество записей, у которых age = 15.

Comment: да уже делал. ошибка в классе оказалась. там на все DELETE был LIMIT 1. Просто думал, что то с запросом не так.